# SQL - Limiting to one row for matching results

Tags: sql, database

Considering the tables below, how would I write a query that returns `profession.profession` when the `profession.profession_id` is present in `contractor_has_profession.profession_id`, but limiting it to one result for each `profession.profession`

So in this example the result would be [Coder, Database, Frontend]

```
contractor_has_profession
contractor_id | profession_id
1             | 5
2             | 5
3             | 5
4             | 2
5             | 1

profession
profession_id | profession
1             | Frontend
2             | Database
3             | Graphics
4             | Sound
5             | Coder
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.profession
FROM   profession p
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   contractor_has_profession c
              WHERE  c.profession_id = p.profession_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this should be sufficient:

```
select distinct p.profession
from profession p
inner join contractor_has_profession c
where p.profession_id = c.profession_id
```

or if I'm wrong here, then try:

```
select p.profession
from profession p
inner join contractor_has_profession c
where p.profession_id = c.profession_id
group by p.profession
```

Comment: This will bring back duplicates then remove them again which isn't conceptually the most efficient way of approaching the problem (definitely in SQL Server `EXISTS` is more efficient - perhaps in MySQL with it's dreadful sub query performance this might perform better though!)

Comment: @Martin I think that it depends , but maybe in fact your solution is faster. Best way is to test at target installation. As you said in your solution we have to do a sub query, joins are a lot faster afaik.

Comment: cheers guys, both solutions work perfectly. Well in my case I don't think speed is an issue. However I might find it easier to use this solution, as I better understand how I would change it to active records more easily (too keep all my query's in one standard).